# Failed to pull dockerhub image on Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I'm using minikube for kubernetes deployment and I am getting this error:

> Failed to pull image
>   "libsynadmin/libsynmp:core-api-kubernetes-0.9.8.1": rpc error: code =
>   Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get
>   https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: TLS handshake timeout ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to create docker registry cache to pull images from since the error indicate slow internet connection

read more at [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running behind company proxy then you have to use minikube start command as follows:

```
minikube start --docker-env HTTP_PROXY=http://$YOURPROXY:PORT \ 
--docker-env HTTPS_PROXY=https://$YOURPROXY:PORT
```

Ref: [minikube issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/530)

Comment: how if I don't have docker?